# Job server with web/email interface to run remote commands

Tags: remote

I'm looking for a solution to run remote commands for my Linux server. Unfortunately I cannot use SSH just only HTTPS (corporate firewall blocks everything different from HTTP/HTTPS on 80/443 ports).

I tried a web shell over HTTPS but it is not comfortable and doesn't suit my needs. I just need something to pass a remote command to the server (optionally check the results), queue the commands to be done sequentially, see the statuses and completion for every job (remote command).

It would be nice to have a job queue-schedule-runner server with a Web GUI.

Another solution that come to my mind is an email interfaced server (I remember something like that from ancient Internet history, but couldn't remember the name) that would run the commands from the emails.

If anybody knows something like that please name any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) for this. It's a stand-alone Java process which can be accessed through a webbrowser. The admin can specify jobs which wil run either a command or a script. A user can then run the job (optionally with parameters).

Output will be sent back to the browser. There is also logging of past-run jobs.

Here is a screenshot from the manual, using jobs:
[image]

Editing jobs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use [AjaxTerm](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AjaxTerm), which is a web based terminal that you can access through a web browser.

[image: ss #1]

Comment: I've quickly tested my server's Webmin Web Shell module and I didn't like it. It was quite slow and there were issues wit copy & paste. Maybe AjaxTerm would be better.

Comment: @ternyk - give it a try, I use it, as my backup access, works well enough for my needs. There are other tools similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/hughperkins/securewebcmd is another possibility (disclaimer: I wrote and maintain it).

- can execute arbitrary commands, though you can whitelist the allowed executables if you want
- keeps a full history of what was run, along with results
- uses nodejs, so quite lightweight to install and run, doesnt need apache etc

[image]